# Prove there is a compact self adjoint $S:H\to H$ such that $S^3=T$.

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, adjoint-operators

Let $T:H\to H$ be compact and self adjoint. Prove there is a compact self adjoint $S:H\to H$ such that $S^3=T$.

Is the $S^3$ means power of 3 or applying the operator 3 times? What is there to prove here? Why wouldn't there be souch $S$?

Where do I start here? I have no idea.

Comment: Yes, $S^3$ means $S$ applied three times. What else could it mean? Exactly what do you have in mind with the alternative "power of $3$"? What there is to prove is that there exists a compact self-adjoint $S$ with $S^3=T$; "why wouldn't there be" is not much of an argument. Where to start: Have you covered the Spectral Theorem? Or talked about the "functional calculus"?

Comment: I know its not much of an argument.. prove $1+1=2$. What is there to prove?

Comment: We didn`t cover the spectral theorem as far as I know. and we did cover functional calculus.

Comment: Try to find a cube root of the 2x2 matrix $\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right]$. Is it also obvious that this matrix has a 2x2 cube root? It will be instructive to try find it.

Comment: _If_ the question was "show that $1+1=2$" then "what is there to prove?" would not be sufficient. In any case, what you're asked to prove here is not obvious.

Comment: @TrialAndError Is there a definition for a cube root over a matrix? I am not familiar with such an operation.

Comment: Oh come on now. $B$ is a cube root of $A$ if $B^3=A$.

Comment: @David if it bothers you to help please don't. I am aloud not to know and I have no wish to irritate no one.

Comment: @TrialAndError is this an elementwise operation such in $ \sqrt[3]{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}} = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt[3]{0} &\sqrt[3]{1}\\\sqrt[3]{0} &\sqrt[3]{0}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$ ?
     \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: No, there is no cube root of such a matrix. There is no 2x2 matrix A for which $A^3$ is the given matrix. Like 1+1=2. Right? That operator is compact on $\mathbb{C}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I voted (+1) for your question because you've got folks stirred up. :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't get it. I was reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator) and trying to understand the meaning of the operator being Compact on $\mathbb C^2$ or $\mathbb R^2$. What did you mean by that?

Comment: @ TrialAndError cant I simply define $S:H\to H$ such that $S^3=T$? After all the question do not restrict $S$ and $T$ by no way other than being compact and adjoint. which part of that statement needs the proof?

Comment: Compact with respect to the Euclidean topology. Every bounded sequence is mapped by A to another bounded sequence, and every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ has a convergent subsequence. That's a distinguishing feature of finite-dimensional normed spaces.

Comment: I gave you an example of an incredibly simple compact linear operator on a two-dimensional space with no square root, cube root, or any other positive integer root. So these things are not obvious. My operator is not selfadjoint though. Selfadjoint really is the key. In fact, compactness is not required, except that you are probably expected to use the fact that your operator has a particular form when it is selfadjoint and compact.

Comment: If I understand you correctly @TrialAndError you are saying that a cube root can only map from $\mathbb C^2$ or $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb C^2$ or $\mathbb R^2$ and cannot say map from $\mathbb C^3$ to $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: So I need to show that given $\langle Tv,w \rangle=\langle v,Tw \rangle$ and $\langle Sv,w \rangle=\langle v,Sw \rangle \implies \exists S$ S.T. $ S^3=T$?

Comment: You won't necessarily get S to be selfadjoint. Is there a selfadjoint cube root of -1 times the identity operator $I$?

Comment: Then I am at lost in terms of what statement to start from.

Comment: @havakok : I think you missed an important part of linear algebras courses, you need to study : real and complex matrices, orthogonal and unitary and projection matrices, diagonalization, matrix norm, trace, determinant, characteristic (and minimal) polynomial, the spectral theorem for symmetric self-adjoint and normal matrices, SVD, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T=0$, then $S=0$ works. If $T$ has a finite-dimensional range and is selfadjoint, then there is an orthonormal set $\{ e_n \}_{n=1}^{N}$ and non-zero real numbers $\{ \lambda_n \}_{n=1}^{N}$ such that
$$
                   Tf = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\lambda_n (f,e_n)e_n.
$$
Then
$$
                     Sf = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\lambda_n}{|\lambda_n|}|\lambda_n|^{1/3}(f,e_n)e_n
$$
is compact, selfadjoint, and satisfies $S^3=T$. A non-finite rank $T$ is compact and selfadjoint iff there exists an orthonormal sequence $\{ e_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and non-zero real $\{ \lambda_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\lim_n \lambda_n = 0$ and
$$
                Tf = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n(f,e_n)e_n .
$$
The same $S$ given above works for $N=\infty$, and is compact because $|\lambda_n|^{1/3}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: What is a finite rank for a linear operation? I couldn't find a reference to this.

Comment: @havakok : Just replace with finite-dimensional range.